# BigQuery LAG returning only nulls

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm facing a problem in bigquery where I'm not getting the desired output using the LAG function:

```sql
WITH
  base AS (
    SELECT "2022-11-01" month , 1100 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-10-01" month , 1000 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-09-01" month , 900 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-08-01" month , 800 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-07-01" month , 700 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-06-01" month , 600 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-05-01" month , 500 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-04-01" month , 400 icount
  )
SELECT
  month,
  icount,
  LAG(icount) OVER w1 AS previous_icount
FROM base
WINDOW w1 AS (
  PARTITION BY month ORDER BY icount)
ORDER BY
  month DESC
```

which results in:

| month | icount | previous_icount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | 1100 | null |
| 2022-10-01 | 1000 | null |
| 2022-09-01 | 900 | null |
| 2022-08-01 | 800 | null |
| 2022-07-01 | 700 | null |
| 2022-06-01 | 600 | null |
| 2022-05-01 | 500 | null |
| 2022-04-01 | 400 | null |

but I was expecting to get the following result:

| month | icount | previous_icount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | 1100 | 1000 |
| 2022-10-01 | 1000 | 900 |
| 2022-09-01 | 900 | 800 |
| 2022-08-01 | 800 | 700 |
| 2022-07-01 | 700 | 600 |
| 2022-06-01 | 600 | 500 |
| 2022-05-01 | 500 | 400 |
| 2022-04-01 | 400 | null |

I went trough the documentation but can't figure what am I missing to get this right.

Comment: would you try `WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY month)`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jaytiger, the issue lies in your window definition.

When partitioning by `month` you apply a treatment for every set of rows that is identified by a unique month.

Since every `month` in your table only has one row, the `LAG` function is applied to partitions that only contain one value, for the corresponding month.
And the `LAG`ged value in this case is `NULL`.

What you want to do is to `PARTITION` your table by something that will keep the different records in the same partition:

- if you had a common column (ex: `shop`) you would partition by this column,
- here you don't have such column so you can `PARTITION BY 1`,
- but in reality you don't even have to `PARTITION`, BigQuery will understand there is only one partition to consider:

```
WITH
  base AS (
    SELECT "2022-11-01" month , 1100 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-10-01" month , 1000 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-09-01" month , 900 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-08-01" month , 800 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-07-01" month , 700 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-06-01" month , 600 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-05-01" month , 500 icount union all
    SELECT "2022-04-01" month , 400 icount
  )
SELECT
  month,
  icount,
  LAG(icount) OVER w1 AS previous_icount
FROM base
WINDOW w1 AS (
  PARTITION BY 1 -- unnecessary 
ORDER BY icount)
ORDER BY
  month DESC
```

Which gives the desired result

[image]